# Mostrar apenas 2 casas decimais

Tags: android, react, api, react-native, axios

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com React Native de conversão de moedas que utiliza uma API externa. Faço contato com essa API utilizando AXIOS. Na renderização está quase tudo certo, gostaria de saber como faço para exibir apenas 2 casas depois da virgula no valor da moeda:

Código de requisição da API com Axios

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = await axios('https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/last/USD-BRL,EUR-BRL,GBP- 
        BRL,JPY-BRL,AUD-BRL,CAD-BRL,CHF-BRL,CNY-BRL,ARS-BRL,TRY-BRL')
        setCoinValue(res.data)
        setLoading(true)
    }
    fetchData();
}, [])
```

Código de exibição da moeda

```
<View style={styles.cardContent}>
   <Text style={styles.currentQuote}>Cotação Atual</Text>
     <View style={styles.values}>
         <Text style={styles.coin1}>US$ 1.00</Text>
         <Text style={styles.coin2} value={moneyCalc}>R$ {coinValue.USDBRL.ask}</Text>
     </View>
</View>
```

Print de como o valor é exibido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que fosse exibido apenas R$ 5.28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o método toFixed:

```
{coinValue.USDBRL.ask.toFixed(2)}
```

Se o valor recebido for uma string, transforme antes, assim:

```
{parseFloat(coinValue.USDBRL.ask).toFixed(2)}</Te
```

Quando se utiliza o método toFixed o retorno é sempre uma string, se precisar transformá-lo novamente em Number após o método, você pode englobar também em um parseFloat, assim:

```
{parseFloat(coinValue.USDBRL.ask.toFixed(2))}
```